# How Rails handles database connection in the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying show controller specific pages in my rails app when the database connection goes away. I do this by catching the Mysql::Error in the rescue_action method and rendering appropriate pages. When the mysql service alone is stopped , i get the Mysql::Error exception really quickly and i could render the pages without any delay.

But when the server itself is shut down, rails takes 3 mins to throw the Mysql::Error and after 5-6 request the whole website becomes unresponsive.

I tried to figure out, which method in rails framework takes such a long time , when the mysql server is shut down. It was a method connection.real_connect (in the active record mysql_adapter file),which took 3 mins to return with an exception.

so i decided to timeout out this method using systemTimer gem. This monkey patch worked perfectly, when i start the website with database connection and immediately shutdown the database server.

But when i start the website with database, and access the website for sometime and then shut down the database server, it doest work at all. and the whole website becomes unresponsive as before. I wonder what is the difference between the two scenarios.

I think i need to know more in detail about how rails handle database connection . how it reacts when the database connection goes off. so that i could identify exact places where i can put monkey patches and make it work for my spefic requirement. I havent seen any relevant article explaining this.

Any help will be very useful for me

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tried this, but you can add `connect_timeout` as one of the specified options (along with port, host, etc) for the MySQL connection in the database.yml file. That value is passed to the real_connect call to establish the connection to MySQL.

Furthermore, since you are experiencing a delay after the initial connection is made and the DB is shutdown, you may need to use the `read_timeout` config option.

Comment: i think, i need to put this patch https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3a802cee0f8cbe209af8886f8f8e8cab204d21a to set the timeouts in my database.yml file. i use a old version of rails (2.1)

Comment: Yeah, should have specified that the added config options I was looking at are in rails 3

Comment: I added this patch (https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3a802cee0f8cbe209af8886f8f8e8cab204d21a)in my rails. and set the connect_timeout read_timeout and write_timeout in database.yml file. the write timeout seem to work i guess(when i shut the datbase server just after starting the website, there is no delay). i dont think the read timeout is getting set, as when i shut the db server after sometime. the website becomes un responsive as before :( any idea why thats happening

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then. The thoughts on what to look at next are 1) what ruby-mysql library are you using 2) perhaps the connection pooling causes issues and 3) possible TCP wait timeout issues?

Comment: The problem seem to be. i was trying to set a value of 0.3 as read_timeout. and 1 for connect_timeout. when i changed the read_timeout to 1. it worked. How can i set decimal values like 0.5 as my read and write timeout??

Comment: The value has to be an unsigned int. But it's unclear from the mysql code and manual whether that timeout value is in seconds or milliseconds.